# Is it valid to omit the return statement of a non-void function template that throw

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, language-lawyer, throw

I am learning C++ using the resources listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, i read about exceptions and want to know if is it valid to omit the return statement of a non-void function/function template that throw as shown below:

**Example 1**

```
#include <iostream>
//this function template does not have a return statement
template<typename T>
T func()
{
    int x = 4;
    std::cout<<"x: "<<x<<std::endl;
    throw;
}

int main()
{
  func<double>();
}
```

**Example 2**

```
#include <iostream>
//this function does not have a return statement
int func()
{
    int x = 4;
    std::cout<<"x: "<<x<<std::endl;
    throw;
}

int main()
{
  func();
}
```

My question is that are example 1 and example 2 valid? Or we have UB/ill-formed.

Comment: Why are you using `throw;` rather than `throw exp;`? Using throw without an object is only really valid from inside a `catch` block (and re-throws the current exception object). Using it outside a catch results in `std::terminate()` being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are example 1 and example 2 valid?

Yes.

> Or we have UB/ill-formed.

No.

> Is it valid to omit the return statement of a non-void function/function template that throw

Yes. A non-void returning function must either throw or return avalue. It cannot do both at the same time.

> So is `int func(){ int x = 4; throw; return x;}` valid

It's valid. But it never returns a value. Everything after the throw is dead code.

Comment: *"A non-void returning function must either throw or return. It cannot do both **at the same time**."* So is `int func(){ int x = 4; throw; return x;}` valid or invalid? Because in the above given example, we have both `throw` and `return` at the same time. So according to your statement, this should be invalid. If not, can you clarify and perhaps add example **what do you mean by at the same time** in your answer.

Comment: _"...A function can terminate by returning or by throwing an exception...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/functions  In this case `or` means you can do either or both in the code, however the function will only exit by one code path.

Comment: I would note that the OP is using the wrong type of throw (should throw an expression).